# Performance differences between controller functions defined on `$scope` or `this` - AngulrJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

In Angular, you can define methods in your controller by attaching them to `$scope`:

```
$scope.myFunction = function () { ... }
```

Of course, you can also attach them to `this`, which I've seen used for communicating between directives and a parent controller:

```
/* within the controller */
this.myFunction = function () { ... }
```

Are there performance differences between the two approaches due to Angular watching the values?

Even if there aren't performance differences, it seems like a nice way of keeping some methods private, so they won't accidentally be accessed from the View.

Comment: i typically set `$scope` to an object created by a "master" constructor function, containing both private and public vars/properties/methods. then any properties assigned to `this` within the constructor will be accessible by the view, while private variables (created with `var`) will not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller):

> NB: Previous versions of Angular (pre 1.0 RC) allowed you to use this interchangeably with the $scope method, but this is no longer the case. Inside of methods defined on the scope this and $scope are interchangeable (angular sets this to $scope), but not otherwise inside your controller constructor.

So `this` is `$scope`, but not for long.

Comment: I'm not sure, but for me this 'Are there performance differences between the two approaches due to Angular watching the values?' is not answered? Or it hasn't performance differences?

Comment: I think "angular sets this to $scope" means that there are no performance differences. They are the same object.

Comment: If this and $scope are the same, then using this without injecting $scope will have better performance. No need for injection.