# What is the 'this' equivalent of $scope.$apply in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS there are two styles of writing controllers, the "the controller as syntax" and the "'attach to $scope' style of controller" (both quotes from the [ngController documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController).) There are several questions on StackOverflow comparing these styles, for example [this vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11605917/575530) and [Performance differences between controller functions defined on `$scope` or `this` - AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18254869/575530).

I have a method on a controller which needs to prompt AngularJS after a model update. Using the $scope style of controller I can do that thus:

```
myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.content = "[Waiting for File]";
    $scope.showFileContent = function(fileContent) {
        $scope.content = fileContent;
        $scope.$apply();
    };
}]);
```

But if I write the controller using 'this'

```
myApp.controller('MainController', function () {
    this.content = "[Waiting for File]";
    this.showFileContent = function(fileContent){
        this.content = fileContent;
    };
});
```

how do I invoke $apply()?

Comment: You can get around using `$apply` by wrapping your async task with `$q`. Have you considered that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really need `$scope`, you still can inject it. Assuming "controller as" syntax:

```
myApp.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
   this.content = "[Waiting for File]";
   $scope.$apply(); // etc.
});
```

The question is, do you really need to run `$scope.$apply()` there? Assuming you are using it properly in "controller as" syntax, it should see it:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController as main">
  <div id="content">{{main.content}}</div>
</div>
```

Then `div#content` will be updated when you update your `this.content` var. Mind you, you need to be careful of how you use `this`, so you might need:

```
myApp.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
   var that = this;
   this.content = "[Waiting for File]";
   this.showFileContent = function(fileContent){
       // 'this' might not be set properly inside your callback, depending on how it is called.
       // main.showFileContent() will work fine, but something else might not
       that.content = fileContent;
   };
});
```

Comment: Thanks @deitch. I was not expecting to need to use `$source.$apply()` either, but [my html is not re-rendering without it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489485/simple-mixture-of-javascript-and-angularjs-not-displaying-file-contents).

Comment: Oh, I see! You are calling `showFileContent()` in response to a `FileReader` event, so the callback is executed outside of the Angular context. Is that it?

Comment: Yeah, also your `onchange` executes stuff outside the Angular context. I will comment on there. It is a separate question.